# Angular error Cannot resolve type entity i11.TreeViewModule to symbol

Tags: angular, angularjs

When finished updating from Angular 13 to Angular 14 on "ng serve" I get this errors.

./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Cannot resolve type entity i11.TreeViewModule to symbol

./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Cannot resolve type entity i11.TreeViewModule to symbol